# What is your recommended Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, lisp

As for me, what I use is as follows recently

yasnippets -- http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/

If there is a good code, Could you introduce it for me?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298065/which-are-the-gnu-emacs-modes-extensions-you-cant-live-without/315722

Comment: Also www.emacswiki.org has lots of code.

Comment: Are you asking if the coding style is good, or are you asking if the functionality is good?  (FWIW, I like yasnippet's namespacing technique.  I would recommend its use in your own code.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Obviously [org-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgMode) and [remember-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RememberMode).
- [Highlight-parentheses](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightParentheses)